# My methods has a list of players with more than one attribute, i want to find the details of the player with least runs scored(Python)

Tags: python, oop

```
class player:
    def __init__(self,name,country,age,matches,runs,wickets):
        self.name=name
        self.country=country
        self.age=age
        self.matches=matches
        self.runs=runs
        self.wickets=wickets
```

#help me writing a method to find the details of least run scored player

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min()` or `sort()` methods with custom key which is the score of the player as:

```
player_with_least_score = min(players, key = lambda x: x.runs) # using min()

players.sort(key = lambda x: x.runs) # players will contain the list of players sorted based on runs
```

Here is sample program with some dummy data:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self,name,country,age,matches,runs,wickets):
        self.name=name
        self.country=country
        self.age=age
        self.matches=matches
        self.runs=runs
        self.wickets=wickets
        
from random import randrange
players = [Player(f"player-{i}", f"country-{i}", randrange(20, 40), 
                  randrange(10, 100), randrange(10, 100), randrange(0, 10)) for i in range(10)]

print("All players")
for player in players:
    print(player.name, player.runs)

print()
player_with_least_score = min(players, key = lambda x: x.runs) # using min
print(f"{player_with_least_score.name} has least score of {player_with_least_score.runs}")


players.sort(key = lambda x: x.runs)     # using sort
#players.sort(key = lambda x: x.runs, reverse=True)  # use reverse=True to sort in decreasing order

print()
print(f"{players[0].name} has least score of {players[0].runs}")
```

Output:

```
All players
player-0 40
player-1 95
player-2 89
player-3 83
player-4 93
player-5 62
player-6 39
player-7 80
player-8 46
player-9 85

player-6 has least score of 39
player-6 has least score of 39
```

Note: The convention is to start class names with a capital letter.